# How do I handle Error in sql queries?

Tags: sql-server

For sql queries like..

```
select Quantity_Books/datepart(hour,Rent_Hour) from Rent_Book where (some conditions..)
```

They will return error when datepart(hour,Rent_Hour) is 0.

If sth like that Happens, I would like to show 0.

I know I should use `case when` But I am not really sure how..

Or any other better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd simply test the value first

```
select
    CASE
       WHEN datepart(hour,Rent_Hour) = 0 THEN 0
       ELSE Quantity_Books/datepart(hour,Rent_Hour)
    END
from
    Rent_Book where (some conditions..)
```

Alternatively, use NULL rules

```
ISNULL((Quantity_Books / (NULLIF(datepart(hour,Rent_Hour), 0))), 0)
```

Comment: you mean..     select ISNULL((Quantity_Books / (NULLIF(datepart(hour,Rent_Hour), 0))), 0) from Rent_Book where (some conditions..) .... ???

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when datepart(hour,Rent_Hour)<>0 then Quantity_Books/datepart(hour,Rent_Hour) else 0 end as col ...
```